# Whenever I try to run an EDIT function, the function goes through, but text is not appended to the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 def EDIT():
    print("\nEnter the file you want to edit")
    command = input('\n$input<<')
    try:
        f = open(command + ".txt", "a")
        f.write(input('\n$append<<'))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('\nSorry, there was an error while trying to create your file. The file doesn\'t exist.\n')
    finally:
        NOTEPAD()
```

Whenever I try to run this specific line of code, the program runs, but when going to check on the file, nothing changes

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the file to flush the buffer.

It's usually best to use a context manager so the file will be closed automatically.

```
def EDIT():
    print("\nEnter the file you want to edit")
    command = input('\n$input<<')
    try:
        with open(command + ".txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(input('\n$append<<'))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('\nSorry, there was an error while trying to create your file. The file doesn\'t exist.\n')
    finally:
        NOTEPAD()
```